# How to use multiple 'or' Boolean operators in an 'if' statement to carry out different types of tasks in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean-logic

I don't really know how word the question but I want the "h" or "j" or "k" inputs to display their respective values

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import random

keyboard = Controller()

wasd = ["w","a","s","d","j","h","k"]

for x in range(1,11):
    if wasd[random.randint(0,6)] == "w":
        keyboard.press("w")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.release("w")
    elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] == "a":
        keyboard.press("a")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.release("a")
    elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] == "s":
        keyboard.press("s")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.release("s")
    elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] == "d":
        keyboard.press("d")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.release("d")
    elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] == "h" or "j" or "k":
        keyboard.press("h" or "j" or "k")
        time.sleep(0.03)
        keyboard.release("h" or "j" or "k")
```

here is the code and this is the output: shdhswhhhh

so whenever its either h, j or k it only types h

Comment: `elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] in "hjk":`

Comment: `elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] in "hjk": keyboard.press("h" or "j" or "k")` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, the following line is incorrect:

```
elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] == "h" or "j" or "k":
```

This line of code is always True because "j" and "k" are non-empty strings that are considered `True` in Python. Therefore, the code block under this condition is executed every time and it always types "h".

To fix this issue, you can change the line to:

```
elif wasd[random.randint(0,6)] in ["h", "j", "k"]:
```

This code will check if the random element from `wasd`. If it is, the code block under this condition will be executed and the corresponding character will be typed.

Also, *`keyboard.press("h" or "j" or "k") will always press "h"`*.

So you can change it to

```
keyboard.press(random.choice(["h", "j", "k"]))
```

---

OP's comment
*" if the result from wasd[random.randint(0,6)] in ["h", "j", "k"] was 'k', then would it not re-choose another letter from the keyboard.press(random.choice(["h", "j", "k"])), making the first choice redundant? "*

For this just save your random choice value in an variable like this

```
for x in range(1,11):
    randomChoice = wasd[random.randint(0,6)]
    if randomChoice == "w":
        keyboard.press("w")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.release("w")
    elif randomChoice == "a":
        keyboard.press("a")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.release("a")
    elif randomChoice == "s":
        keyboard.press("s")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.release("s")
    elif randomChoice == "d":
        keyboard.press("d")
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.release("d")
    elif randomChoice == "h" or "j" or "k":
        keyboard.press(randomChoice)
        time.sleep(0.03)
        keyboard.release(randomChoice)
```

Q2. what is the random.choice thing for?

**Ans. It is a function that chooses a random value from a given sequence.**

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but what is the `random.choice` thing for? and also, wouldn't it reshuffle the choice, for example, if the result from `wasd[random.randint(0,6)] in ["h", "j", "k"]` was 'k', then would it not re-choose another letter from the `keyboard.press(random.choice(["h", "j", "k"]))`, making the first choice redundant?